# How to remove span wrapper in CF7 and keep errors

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7, contact-form

I would like to remove all unnecessary span wrappers from Contact form 7.
For this I use the following filter:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {

    $content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);
    $content = str_replace('<br />', '', $content);
    
    return $content;
});
```

But t**his automatically removes the display of errors on the form** (the error that appears under each invalid field). Because the plugin uses `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">` to position the error display.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: _“Because the plugin uses `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">` to position the error display.”_ - are you talking about CSS absolute positioning here, that does not work any more, when those wrapping span elements are missing - or what exactly? (Apparently those elements did rather not actually qualify for your categorization as “unnecessary” to begin with then, huh? So why do you want to remove them then?)

Comment: no mate `[textarea* company_introduction id:company_introduction class:effect x3] <span class="focus-border"></span>` this is what I use in my contact form. I have to delete the span wrapper dynamycally created because the focus border effect doesn't work anymore. the span wraps my textarea, while I need the "focus-border" to be directly after the textarea

Comment: `<span class="focus-border"></span>` is not something CF7 uses by default, but rather your own addition here? _“I have to delete the span wrapper dynamycally created because the focus border effect doesn't work anymore”_ - and that means what, _exactly_? Sounds like something that should be fixed by modifying the applied CSS, rather than messing with the DOM structure, so far.

Comment: I just want to apply a border effect on my textarea. You can see it in action [link](https://www.barryand.co/form/)

Comment: And how exactly are the additional span wrapper elements (which you seem to have removed there already), hinder you from doing that?

Comment: if I put the span again, the textarea will be wrapped by the span. and the focus-border span will no longer be directly after my textarea. Then the effect won't be possible anymore
This is the CSS I use.`textarea.effect ~ .focus-border{position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 0; height: 1px; background-color: black;     transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.94, 0.6, 1) 0s;}
textarea.effect:focus ~ .focus-border{width: 100%; transition: width 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.94, 0.6, 1) 0s;}`

Comment: You should probably be able to simply rewrite this using [`:focus-within`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)  instead.

Comment: Or just use a tiny JavaScript, that moves those `.focus-border` elements _into_ the span wrapper, once the page has loaded (or creates them dynamically to begin with, so that you don’t have to type them into your form configuration any more in the first place.)